# Different type of object for admin and user

Tags: php, oop

I am building an intranet application and i want to be able to have 2 different types of users a regular user and an admin user. I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to go about doing this. Either to have one object for admin type stuff and then one object for user type stuff. Or combine both of that into one object. But i keep getting stuck and not sure how to go about doing that, or if that is even the best way.

Lets say I have the following situations:

```
1. query the db to get all tasks for all projects that are active.
    Admin Query
2. query the db to get all tasks for all projects that are due today and active.
    Admin Query
3. Query the db to get all tasks for a specific project that are active.
    Admin Query
    User Query
4. Query the db to get all tasks for a specific project that are active and due today.
    Admin Query
    User Query
5. Query the db to get all tasks for a specific project.
    Admin Query
    User Query
6. Query the db to get all tasks for a specific project, with different status specified.
    Admin Query
7. Any one of those queries has an optional parameter to either get the count or the data.
```

I started the following object but now im a little stuck as which route to go:

```
public function getTasks($status, $project, $type = "count", $duetoday = NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            if($duetoday != NULL){
                $today = date("Y-m-d"); 
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status=:status
                                            AND $project=:project AND duedate BETWEEN :duedate 
                                            AND :duedate");
                $stmt->execute(array(':status'=>$status,':project'=>$project,':duedate'=>$today));
            }else{
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE status=:status
                                            AND $project=:project");
                $stmt->execute(array(':status'=>$status,':project'=>$project)); 
            }

            $tasks=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
            {
                if($type == "count"){
                    return $stmt->rowCount();
                }else{
                    return $tasks;
                }
            }else{
                return false;   
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Is your function running right now? What is it doing wrong? Is your goal to actually generate sql, or what objects would your application have?

Comment: stuck meaning, not sure how to accomplish what i want. I just want to make sure i'm going about this object in the right way or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: what is the goal of the object? generating sql for the different queries listed in your question? (Sorry for being obtuse, I'm just trying to get this right)

Comment: Well i guess but actually performing the query as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start with some words about the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Basically, this means that an object and it's behaviors should have one responsibility. Here, I think your getTasks method is a good opportunity to refactor some code into better object oriented code.

There are actually many things it is doing:

- Generate sql
- Execute a query
- Control the flow of the program

The method generating sql should not have to worry about it's execution, and the method executing it should not have to worry about getting it. This, as a side effect, will also reduce the nesting in a single method.

There is a lot of code to write, which I'll let you do, but if you create classes that implements those interfaces and a controller to use them, you should be able to get through this and write easier to maintain / refactor code:

```
interface SqlGenerating {
    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
    public function makeSql(array $params);

    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @return array
     */
    public function makeValues(array $params);
}

interface DBAccessing {
    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo);

    /**
     * @param string $sql
     * @param array $values
     * @return PDOStatement
     */
    public function getStmt($sql, array $values = []);
}

class Controller {
    public function __construct(SqlGenerating $sqlGenerator, DBAccessing $dbAccess) {
        // associate to private properties
    }
    public function getTasks($status, $project, $type = "count", $duetoday = null) {
        // this function will use the sqlGenerator and the dbAccess to query the db
        // this function knows to return the count or the actual rows
    }
}
```

If you haven't already, this is a good time to learn about type-hinting in functions. This requires your function to be passed an object (or an array) to be assured of the behavior of the function. Also, you will notice that I type-hinted the *interfaces* into the controller. This is to actually be able to switch classes if ever you need a different one to manage sql and db access.

Comment: wow, that was definitely an amazing explanation, i am going to try an implement this in my class now and see if i can get it to work. Thanks a lot for your help